# Can't update files on the wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress, fileupdate

I'am getting the message "Can not send a message to the site to verify the absence of fatal errors. As a result, the PHP modification has been canceled. You will need to upload your modified PHP file by other means, for example using an FTP client." when i try to update files on the wordpress editor, i've noticed this error after the last wordpress update.

Thanks,

Comment: can you check the file permission via FTP

Comment: I tried to change the file permission but in vain, i thinks it's related to the new wordpress version!!

Comment: what is the file permission?

Comment: The file permission is 775

Comment: What you trying to update? Please update the code here

Comment: im trying to update files on the wordpress appearance > editor. I get this error "Can not send a message to the site to verify the absence of fatal errors. As a result, the PHP modification has been canceled. You will need to upload your modified PHP file by other means, for example using an FTP client."

Comment: You re trying to update the code has error. Please check the code

Comment: Indeed, Thanks @vel

Comment: I have added answer for future users. Accept the answer if it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update the code has error. Please check the code.